# Design of account e-mail activation (with Hibernate in mind)

Tags: hibernate

I have a design problem which I would like some input on. Here are the constraints:

1. Each user must have a working e-mail address when registering their account. When registering their user account an activation email should be sent, containing a link with an activation code which must be followed for the account to be activated.
2. Each user account exists in exactly one office which exists in exactly one company.
3. The first registered user from a company creates the company and one office. The rest of the company users are then invited by the first user.
4. The companies may interact with each other, but only if the companies first users are activated (i.e. they clicked their respective activation links after registering).

Here is a small UML-diagram of how it could be solved:

[image]

In the above diagram some details are left out. The diagram shows classes and fields only. When it comes to fields they're just used conceptually to show which information should be stored, please ignore their scope.

Some thoughts and questions:

- User and NotActivatedUser are mostly the same. Should they be one single class or separated? If they are separated, which form of Hibernate inheritance persistence would you use?
- If an account isn't activated after a certain time it should be removed. If it was the first user, which also created the users Company and Office both of these should be removed too. Do we need NotActivatedOffice and NotActivatedCompany as well? (For clean separation in the database.)

How would you design this kind of solution? Do you feel keeping non active and active entities separate in the database is important? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use inheritance to represent a state (activated/deactivated) of your User objects. Composition (aggregation) is a much better choice here.

By using aggregation, AbstractUser simply becomes User. You may wish to model the Activation with a class instead of polluting the User class with activation related attributes. This way you get a nice and clean object model.

At the database level you can still decide to store the two objects in the same table/record, known as [Component mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/components.html). Or you can decide to store User and Activation in separate tables (aka [Entity mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/fr/html/entity.html)).

Hibernate supports both type of mappings, it's mostly a matter of configuration.

The User class would contain the following attributes:

- givenName
- surname
- email
- activation (reference to an Activation object)

The Activation class would contain the following attributes:

- activationCode (string)
- sentOn (when was the email sent)
- activatedOn (defaults to null, set to current date/time when the user clicks the activation link, tells the system if the user has activated his account when not null)

You could use an HQL Query to know which company has at least one activated user:

```
from Office o 
   left join fetch o.company 
where 
   o.administrator.activatedOn != null
```

This query assumes that you have defined an 'administrator' attribute in your Office class. The 'administrator' would be a reference to the User who created the Office. In the database, the 'offices' table has a foreign key to a User record.

By modeling the relationship this way, you may change the Administrator of an Office (example, he left or got fired from the Office/Company). It all depends on your use cases ...

I also added a sentOn attribute to the Activation class used to cleanup inactivated account after a certain time (was missing in your UML diagram).

Answer (score 0):

I would not separate the NotActivatedUser from the ActivatedUser; just have a User table, and have a column for "Activated", defaulting to 0 (not activated).

One thing; I'd split out the activation code to a separate table, perhaps with "ActivationMethod".  This allows for extensibility in the future if you want to have a way for a user to activate their account other than email, and also serves the purpose of removing the "activationCode" column from the User table.

I wouldn't worry about unactivated Offices and Companies; according to your usage plans as described above, they shouldn't be able to be used by anyone else until that user activates himself (and therefore the Office and Company).  One question; why do you allow a non-activated user to create an Office and Company?  Why not restrict that activity to only activated users?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't write two classes for activated and non-activated users, because it is just a state. If this state before the activation gets complex, you can reference to a activation state or the like.

If you have a "OfficeOwner" flag on the user, you know when to remove the office without any complex logic.

Comment: The office owner flag seems unnecessary; it should be a really simple query to find offices created by a given user.

Comment: Only if you have a back reference from the office to the user. This would be another option.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same table for activated and non-activated users requires you to check the status of the user, as well as that of the offices and companies everywhere in the application.

For that reason I would probably use an activationrequest table with all the information needed to create the user, the office ant the company when the activation is performed.